# how to create a function to accept any call from any object of any structure?

Tags: go, structure

In golang I am trying to create a function which I want to call it with an object of a structure.

How can I make the function accept calls from all types of structures.

calling function:

```
func (this PortStatsHandler) triggerSampler(counter int) {
     portstatob.GenerateStats(ctime) //portstatob is an object.

}
```

function:

```
func (this *PortStats) GenerateStats(ctime time.Time) {

}
```

Now it's accepting only objects of `PortStats` but not any structure.

Comment: If you're looking for anything that defines `GenerateStats(ctime time.Time)`, that's what an `interface` is. Have you gone through any documentation like [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) or the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately go doesn't have generics and the answer to your question is - it's impossible.

The only thing you can do here is create regular function and pass object into function as parameter.